# Where can I find the list of methods and properties in Settings.Default namepsace in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am working on a project that uses some plugins. These plugins are introduced during the run time. So i want to write on the data types of these plugins during run time. If i just want to save the changed settings during run time by using user settings and not use the customs file then what methods or properties should i use? I am trying to find out the list of methods for settings.default namespace in msdn but cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
```

The settings class will derive from that class.